# I get warnings when compiling

Tags: c++, oop, structure

This is my structure:

```
struct player {
    string name;
    string surname;
    int goals;
    string tim;

};
```

This is my function:

```
void read(player* x, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        cout << "************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "Name:";
        cin >> x->name;
        cout << endl << "Surname:";
        cin >> x->surname;
        cout << endl << "Goals :";
        cin >> x->goals;
        cout << endl << "Name of the team:";
        cin >> x->tim;
        x++;
    }
}
```

While I compile, I get this warning:

> Warning   C26495  Variable 'player::goals' is uninitialized. Always
>   initialize a member variable (type.6).

I don't understand why?

Comment: `string` has a default constructor but `int` doesn't

Comment: Which line in your code generates the warning?  It doesn't appear to be in the code you've shown, since you never read from `goals`.

Answer (score 0):

You might solve the warning with:

```
struct player {
    string name;
    string surname;
    int goals = 0;
    string tim;
};
```

Issue with uninitialized variables is that it is UB to read them before to write value first. With initialization, we avoid that UB.

Answer (score 0):

Although they look similar, `int` and `string` are rather different in that `int` is a fundamental type whereas `string` is a class.

Classes can have default constructors and therefore will automatically initialize to a sensible value (`""` in the case of a string). fundamental types just acquire whatever bit pattern happened to be at the location they are stored in.

Applying an initializer will for fundamental types ot initialize to zero, so:

```
struct player {
    string name;
    string surname;
    int goals {};
    string tim;
};
```

Since it makes no difference to classes, you might want to get into the habit of using it always:

```
struct player {
    string name {};
    string surname {};
    int goals {};
    string tim {};
};
```